# float members in C structures not working: Code::blocks IDE issue

Tags: c

I do not know what is wrong with the following program. It does not take inputs to the structure members properly. I am using code::blocks and no solutions suggested on the internet seems to be working. All suggestions are for Turbo C and Borland C. Please help guys. This is my program:

```
main()
{
    struct book
    {
        char name;
        float price;
        int pages;
    };
    struct book b[3];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n Enter name, price and pages: \t\t");
        scanf("%c %f %d",&b[i].name,&b[i].price,&b[i].pages);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%c, %f, %d", b[i].name,b[i].price,b[i].pages);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should tell us why you think it's wrong. Is it crashing, giving you the wrong result?

Comment: We don't know what's wrong with it either, because you haven't told us. What do you expect it to do, what is it actually doing, and how do they differ? And why is `name` a single character?

Comment: Sir, first structure array element takes the inputs fine. While inputting the values for the second array element, the control goes to the third array element b[2] before completion of the input process. I just don't understand why this happens.

Comment: It is hard to find a book with a `1-char` long name. It appears you intended `char name[NUM];`. Your next problem will be book names generally have spaces in their titles. `scanf` without delimiters other than space is difficult to use. While you can declare `struct book` within `main()` (which should be `int main (void)`), it will make it impossible to pass as a parameter to any future function that may need it. Suggest declaring `struct book {...}` above main in the file. If you are on Win7 (or anything using C89), you will need `return 0;` before the closing `}`.

Comment: 1) Add leading space  `scanf(" %c %f %d"...` 2)  Check `scanf()` return value.  Note: Few books have 1 letter titles.

Comment: struct book
    {
        char name[20];
        float price;
        int pages;
    };
main()
{

    struct book b[3];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n Enter name, price and pages: \t\t");
        scanf(" %s %f %d",b[i].name,&b[i].price,&b[i].pages);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s, %f, %d", b[i].name,b[i].price,b[i].pages);
    }
    getch();
}

Comment: Even this does not work, sirs.

Comment: I think it is because of the float member "price" in there. How to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

The primary question **float members in C structures not working**, is one that we all pretty much know isn't the case. The problem is (as with most new C programmers using `scanf`) most likely with your `scanf` *format string*.

Before addressing the code itself, a few general helpful hints. **Enable compiler warnings** (check the Borland, Turbo reference for what to add to the compiler options in Code::Blocks). I must admit I haven't used Borland C since '91 or '92, so I don't have the compiler string options at hand.

Space your code so it is readable. Young eyes may have no problems with all the code smushed together, but for the rest, a bit of spacing helps.

A real-world bit of advise -- *Never use floating-point numbers for currency*. Rounding will make money disappear (or appear).

The two valid invocations of `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (and there are implementation environment options that some compilers allow)

While you can declare `struct book` within `main()`, its declaration is local to `main()` meaning it will not be declared outside of `main()` and will be unavailable to any function that may need to help handle the books data. Better to make the `struc book` declaration global.

Since a book `name` generally has more than one character, (there are way more than 26 books) it is unlikely that you intended `char name;`. More likely you intended `name` to be an array that can hold the complete book name. The simplest fix is the declare `name` as a fixed length array using a constant (e.g. `#define MAXC 256 ... char name[MAXC]; ...`).

Using an array on the data you describe and taking the input as a single line of user input exposes another problem with `scanf`. (how do you tell it where the title ends if it has spaces in it?) Separating the calls to `scanf` to read each bit of the book information in a separate call will help (left to you).

Lastly, when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you generate a `'\n'` in the input buffer. When you attempt to read the next `name`, the `'\n'` from the previous <kbd>Enter</kbd> remains in the input buffer and the `%c` *format specifier* happily takes that as your next character. Adding a `" "` (space) before your first *format specifier* (as mentioned by chux), will consume all whitespace (a newline being whitespace) so that your character (or string) is filled properly.

Putting that together, you could do something similar to the following (which you should expand on):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NBOOKS 3        /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 256

struct book {           /* struct book defined globally */
    char name[MAXC];    /* name declared as an array for multiple chars */
    float price;        /* never use floating-point for currency */
    int pages;
};

int main (void) {

    struct book b[NBOOKS] = {{ "", 0.0, 0 }};    /* initialize your struct */
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NBOOKS; i++) {
        printf ("\n Enter name, price and pages: \t\t");
        /* validate ALL user input */
        if (scanf (" %s %f %d", b[i].name, &b[i]. price,&b[i].pages) != 3) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    putchar ('\n');
    for (i = 0; i < NBOOKS; i++) /* output books */
        printf ("%s, %f, %d\n", b[i].name, b[i].price, b[i].pages);

#if defined (__WIN32) || defined (__WIN64)
    getchar();  /* don't use getch(); it is 100% non-portable */
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/bookstruct

 Enter name, price and pages:           book_1(no_spaces_in_name)  28.50 200

 Enter name, price and pages:           book_2 22.8 123

 Enter name, price and pages:           book_3 104.95 745

book_1(no_spaces_in_name), 28.500000, 200
book_2, 22.799999, 123
book_3, 104.949997, 745
```

(**note:** if you look at the prices stored as a `float`, you can see first-hand why you never want to use floating-point numbers for currency)

Look things over and let us know if you have further questions.

**Follow-up From Comments**

When you begin wanting to enter multi-word titles, your are better off moving to a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets` or POSIX `getline`. **Never, never, never** use `gets`. It is so prone to buffer overrun, it has been removed from the C11 standard.

The only trick with *line-oriented* input functions is the read (and include) the trailing `'\n'` in the buffer they fill. It can easily be trimmed.

However, in using the line-oriented approach for the multi-word read of `name`, you now need to make two input calls with `fgets`, the first for `name` and then a second for `print` and `pages`. The second buffer can be parsed with `sscanf` to separate `price` and `pages`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NBOOKS 3        /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 256

struct book {           /* struct book defined globally */
    char name[MAXC];    /* name declared as an array for multiple chars */
    float price;        /* never use floating-point for currency */
    int pages;
};

int main (void) {

    struct book b[NBOOKS] = {{ "", 0.0, 0 }};    /* initialize your struct */
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NBOOKS; i++) {
        size_t len = 0;
        char buf[MAXC] = "";
        printf ("book[%d] enter name: ", i+1);
        /* validate ALL user input */
        if (!fgets (b[i].name, MAXC, stdin)) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for name.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        len = strlen (b[i].name);
        if (len && b[i].name[len-1] == '\n')
            b[i].name[len-1] = 0;

        printf ("book[%d] enter price & pages: ", i+1);
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for price & pages.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (sscanf (buf, "%f %d", &b[i].price, &b[i].pages) != 2) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input price & pages.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    putchar ('\n');
    for (i = 0; i < NBOOKS; i++) /* output books */
        printf ("%-24s %7.2f     %d\n", b[i].name, b[i].price, b[i].pages);

#if defined (__WIN32) || defined (__WIN64)
    getchar();  /* don't use getch(); it is 100% non-portable */
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/bookstruct
book[1] enter name: Tom Sawyer
book[1] enter price & pages: 23.95 287
book[2] enter name: Learning C Takes Time
book[2] enter price & pages: 521.99 10000
book[3] enter name: The Last Iceberg
book[3] enter price & pages: 290.19 385

Tom Sawyer                 23.95     287
Learning C Takes Time     521.99     10000
The Last Iceberg          290.19     385
```

Look the new information over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you very very much David sir! I think it worked...

Comment: Glad it helped. There is a lot to learn with C. Just take your time, keep at it and you will do fine.

Comment: David Sir,  why can't I enter the two strings name and roll_no with the following code.. Next iteration happens even before the completion of the first set of inputs......................................................................   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n Enter name, price and pages: \t\t");
        gets(std[i].name); gets(std[i].roll_no);
        scanf(" %f",&std[i].prcnt);
    }

Comment: That has to do with the `%s` format specifier. It stops reading on the **first whitespace**. Meaning when it hits the first space it stops reading leaving everything else in `stdin` unchanged. To read a multiword string, make the call for the book name as a separate call, e.g. `scanf (" %[^/n]", b[i].name);`, That means you prompt for the book name (read it), then prompt for the price and pages and read with `scanf ("%f %d", &b[i]. price,&b[i].pages)`. Now you can enter a name up to 255 chars including spaces. **Never, never, never** use `gets`, it is insecure and removed from C11.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the input buffer when you use scanf function to input values type of char, otherwise the “\n” will be the parameters of scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct book
    {
        char name;
        float price;
        int pages;
    };
    struct book b[3];
    int i;
    char c;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n Enter name, price and pages: \t\t");
        scanf("%c %f %d",&b[i].name,&b[i].price,&b[i].pages);
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        ;
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%c, %f, %d", b[i].name,b[i].price,b[i].pages);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: What about the following sir:

Comment: for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n Enter name, price and pages: \t\t");
        gets(std[i].name); gets(std[i].roll_no);
        scanf(" %f",&std[i].prcnt);
    }

Comment: There are two strings to be inputted before a float but the iteration happens before input completion..

Comment: When you input a float number, you will input an "\n" by pressing "Enter", and the  "\n" will be a parameter of scanf function。 Therefor the iteration happens before input completion.

Comment: add "int c; while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); " after the scanf function.